# How can my confidence interval and p-value not be in line with each other in a linear difference-in-difference analysis in R?

Tags: r, multiple-regression, linear, logarithm, difference-in-difference

I'm performing a linear difference-in-difference analysis with mental health care costs, log transformed (log10), as outcome measurement. Individuals are placed in a treatment or control group, and I correct for several covariates (age, gender etc).

I've already performed a logistic difference-in-difference analysis with another outcome (referred to mental health care yes or no) and that result was fine/normal and as expected. Therefore,  my data is assumed correct.

With my linear difference-in-difference analysis I get very low estimates, even after back transforming the log (with exp and 10^ to be sure)(which I can live with if the following problem did not occur). Also, my confidence intervals are not in line with the p-values. For my beta 1.515 (CI: 1.489-1.538) the p-value is <0.001 and for my other beta of 0.993 (CI: 0.972 - 1.015) the p-value is 0.547. This is strange because the 0 is not in the first CI but still significant..

```
lm <- lm(Costs  ~ CT_GROUP + Dummy_PrePost + Int_DumPOH_DumPrePost + Dum2_2015 + Dum3_2016, data = HUI_DID)
summary(lm)
summary(lm)$coefficients[,"Estimate"]
confint(lm)
exp(summary(lm)$coefficients[,"Estimate"]) #old
exp(confint(lm)) #Confidence Interval of the Estimated β1 #old
10^(summary(lm)$coefficients[,"Estimate"])
10^(confint(lm))
```

[image: Here is my complete table/outcome of the analysis mentioned above]

Everything seems normal, does anyone has a suggestion?
Thank you!

Comment: Based on your table, the p-values appear to correspond to the point null hypothesis beta = 1. If that's the case, the CIs and p-values are consistent. If you are showing the transformed values, i.e. 10^x, that makes sense.

Comment: Hi Robert, thank you. But it should only be statistical significant if the 0 is in the CI, like in a normal linear regression right? I think I don't understand why in the DiD-analyses 1 is correct.. I showed the estimated that I got after I backtransformed the estimate with 10^.

Comment: Before making the transformations do your p-values align with the CIs? They probably do. I think that your transformation is causing the CIs to wrap around 1.

Comment: @Joella, if a result is not significant, the 95% CI once transformed exponentially should include 1

Comment: Hi, thank you for your anwsers. My p-values do aligh with the CIs before the transformations. Can somebody explain to me why they become around 1 instead of 0 after the transformation? Or provide some literture to support that statement?

Comment: Ho: beta = 0 is transformed to Ho: 10^beta = 10^0, i.e. = 1.